# Python: Assign list to multidimensional array element

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do an assignment to a multidimensional array where each element of the array is 3 short integers:

```
a = ndarray([3,3,3], dtype='u2,u2,u2')
a[2,2,2] = [1,2,3]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>      a[2,2,2] = [1,2,3]
>   TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

I am going to be using a large array and would like to get direct indexing into the array for performance. What is a good way to do this in python?

Thanks for any insight into how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of an array of `dtype='u2,u2,u2'` are a *tuple* of three shorts, not a *list* of three shorts. So:

```
a[2,2,2] = (1,2,3)
```

(The parens are of course not necessary, but I used them to make it obvious this is a tuple.)

You can also pass it an `array` if you want:

```
a[2,2,2] = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Of course the error message here certainly could be better… What it's actually complaining about is something deeper than what you'd expect, and it doesn't help you debug the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.That helps. If I am getting a list as a parameter in to a function, do I have to convert it to a tuple to do the assignment to the array? What is the most efficient way to assign 3 numerical coordinates coming as a function parameter to an array element? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure whether calling `a[x,y,z] = tuple(foo)` is faster or slower than `a[x,y,z] = np.array(foo)`; if it matters, test it. But I doubt it will matter. If it matters, it's probably because you're doing it in a big loop—in which case the fact that you're looping in Python instead of vectorizing is the real problem you need to solve.